# My site is broken, it displays a "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in"

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Today I found this error on my Wordpress site

```
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in
```

The website worked just fine yesterday and today I got this error.

Comment: Please add your code. We can barely help without.

Comment: What was PHP version yesterday on your server and what is today? Any Wordpress core updates since yesterday as well?